# Sorting by other fields in sub-aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have an index with documents that look like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    carId: 1,
    carName: 'Toyota Matrix',
    carClass: 'Compact',
    insured: false
}
```

Is it possible to have one Elasticsearch query that will allow me to have a table with Car ID, Car Name, Car class, and # Insured (through an aggregation), and have each column sortable? The table would look something like this:

```
Car ID | Car name      | Car class | # Insured
-------------------------------------------------------------
     1 | Toyota Matrix | Compact   | 123
     2 | Ford F-150    | Truck     | 78
   ...
```

I know I can create an aggregation on car ID, and then a sub-aggregation on # insured; something like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "car_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "carId"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "insured": { 
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "insured": "T"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in doing this, I can sort by either car ID or # insured. However, I can't sort by either car name or car class. If I create a sub-aggregation on car name or car class, it's not a single-value aggregation, so I can't sort by it.

Is there any way I could sort by these other fields in an aggregation?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question????

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand your real question but in order to sort multiple field here is the way to do it https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html i believe you dont even need aggregation

```
{
    "sort" : [
        { "insured" : "desc" },
        { "car_name" : "desc" },
        { "car_id" : "desc" },
        ...
    ],
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
```